# Вход на сетевой ресурс без пароля.

Tags: сеть, доступ

Доброго всем здравия.
Есть ПК, на нём расшаренные ресурсы, ПК управляется не мной.
При каждом выходе из ОС, и заходя на тот ПК, постоянно требуется вводить, допустим "user"и без пароля, просто Энтэр и входим.
Как можно это обойти?
через runas, как-то не получилось.
использую следующее:

```
runas /profile /savecred /user:domain_name\user "\\192.X.X.X\consultant\cons.exe"
```

Возникает второй вопрос:
Почему через Windows окошко пускает? Т.е. написал "user", пароль оставил пустым и Энтэр и всё работает.
А как сделать через cmd? Облегчить жизнь пользователям?
Почему runas не воспринимает пустой пароль?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так думаю, что описана ситуация в рабочей группе компов. Вариантов у вас вобщем много: 1. Поправить локальные политики для возможности использования пустых паролей (но я бы не рекомендовал, огребёте эпидемию в конце концов). 2. Запаролить ресурс и запомнить пасс средствами винды (вариантик так себе, но лучше 1-го). 3. Наладить нормальный домен и наслаждаться счастьем (дорого из-за стоимости винды, но красиво, понятно и удобно). 4. Поднять ресурс на самбе (дешево, надежно, но нужны знания юниксов). 5. Юзать FreeNAS (есть такое очень красивое GUI-ёвое решение). Остались вопросы - добро пожаловать с ними на мой сайт (указан в профиле). Да, забыл, можно ещё учётку гостя включить, но я бы тоже этого делать не стал ;)

Comment: Всё ответы верны. Спасибо! Но они верны для того, кто управляет шарой. Тем ресурсом управляет главный корпус. Но не я. Вот в этом-то и фича.  Хотел облегчить жизнь юзерам.  Придётся бегать по всем компам и "запоминать пароль". Думал обойти со стороны клиента как-нибудь.

Comment: Нет-нет, уважаемый, в рабочей группе есть такая особенность, что если на компе с общим ресурсом имена пользователей, разрешённых в списке доступа, совпадают с именами пользователей удалённых компьютеров, то права доступа передаются и пользователям на удалённых компах. Главное чтобы имена пользунов совпадали. Если вам не критично, чтобы каждый юзер логинился под своим ником - то вам и карты (точнее, клавиатура с мышью) в руки. (Продолжение в след. комментарии, не хватает места :) )

Comment: А бегать по всем компам (ну для начала, конечно, придётся), но я бы на вашем месте сделал бы на общей шаре несколько VBS-скриптов и при первой (и последней) "пробежке" по компам настроил бы автозапуск их при логине. Поттом, чтобы сделать какие-либо изменения на всех компах (ну или отдельных) вам бы пришлось лишь изменить соответствующий скрипт. При логине указанные изменения бы применились ;)

Comment: Спасибо, вот что юзеры с похожими именами попадать на ПК могут, это я знал. А что им полностью права передаются, как-то в голову не приходило.